# Iterator cannot find symbol method add()

Tags: java

I am trying to iterate through an arraylist and add a new Book (custom class) to the list based on a certain condition.  My addBook function is below. The line bookIter.add() is giving me the error: 'cannot find symbol method add(Book)'.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
public void addBook(String title, String authors, String publisher, int year) {
    Iterator<Book> bookIter;
    bookIter = this.books.iterator();

    if (this.books.isEmpty()) {
        this.books.add(new Book(title, authors, publisher, year));
        System.out.println(this.books.toString());
    } else {
        while (bookIter.hasNext()) {
            Book book = bookIter.next();
            if (book.getYear() == year) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate Years. Please try again.");
            } else {
                bookIter.add(new Book(title, authors, publisher, year));
                System.out.println(this.books.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Iterator class is meant for iterating very quickly over a list, not to modify, even if you add to the list you instantiated the iterator from, at the moment of iterating, it will raise an exception.

Comment: @Abderrahimben A `ListIterator` can be used for adding to the underlying list, without raising that exception. It's designed for this purpose. And any `Iterator` may allow removing items, so modification is actually acceptable with an `Iterator`.

Comment: Additionally, it's clearer to open that iterator inside your conditional, since you're just ignoring it if the list is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Iterator` does not contain `add()` method ,`ListIterator` does.

Try changing it to this:

```
ListIterator<Book> bookIter;
bookIter = this.books.listIterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

No add method for a "simple" iterator.

An iterator, which is an object that implements either the Iterator or one of  the iterator subinterfaces.

Iterator enables you to cycle through a collection, obtaining or removing elements. ListIterator extends Iterator to allow bidirectional traversal of a list, and the modification of elements.

The Methods Declared by Iterator:

```
boolean hasNext( )
Object next( )
void remove( )
forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action)
```

The Methods Declared by ListIterator:

```
void add(Object obj)
boolean hasNext( )
boolean hasPrevious( )
Object next( )
int nextIndex( )
Object previous( )
int previousIndex( )
void remove( )
void set(Object obj)
forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action)
```

check this quick tutorial : [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm)

[javadoc iterator this way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

[javadoc listiterator that way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)